# Как заменить нули во фрейме данных на определенные значения?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Как получить из такого фрейма данных:

```
df =

Date        m-t vil
3/15/1990   11  0
3/16/1990   11  3.98
3/19/1990   12  0
3/20/1990   12  0
3/21/1990   12  0
3/22/1990   12  0
3/23/1990   12  -4.69
3/26/1990   13  0
3/27/1990   13  0
3/28/1990   13  0
3/29/1990   13  0
3/30/1990   13  2.72
4/2/1990    14  0
4/3/1990    14  0
4/4/1990    14  0
4/5/1990    14  0
4/6/1990    14  0.14
```

Такой:

```
Date        m-t vil
3/15/1990   11  3.98
3/16/1990   11  3.98
3/19/1990   12  -4.69
3/20/1990   12  -4.69
3/21/1990   12  -4.69
3/22/1990   12  -4.69
3/23/1990   12  -4.69
3/26/1990   13  2.72
3/27/1990   13  2.72
3/28/1990   13  2.72
3/29/1990   13  2.72
3/30/1990   13  2.72
4/2/1990    14  0.14
4/3/1990    14  0.14
4/4/1990    14  0.14
4/5/1990    14  0.14
4/6/1990    14  0.14
```

То есть, заменить нули в колонке `vil`, на последние числа (не знаю как правильно сказать).

[Ссылка на файл с данными](https://dropmefiles.com/j9pGF).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Замените нули на `NaN` и воспользуйтесь методом [Series.bfill()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.bfill.html):

```
df["vil"] = df["vil"].replace(0, np.nan).bfill()
```

результат:

```
In [228]: df
Out[228]:
         Date  m-t   vil
0   3/15/1990   11  3.98
1   3/16/1990   11  3.98
2   3/19/1990   12 -4.69
3   3/20/1990   12 -4.69
4   3/21/1990   12 -4.69
5   3/22/1990   12 -4.69
6   3/23/1990   12 -4.69
7   3/26/1990   13  2.72
8   3/27/1990   13  2.72
9   3/28/1990   13  2.72
10  3/29/1990   13  2.72
11  3/30/1990   13  2.72
12   4/2/1990   14  0.14
13   4/3/1990   14  0.14
14   4/4/1990   14  0.14
15   4/5/1990   14  0.14
16   4/6/1990   14  0.14
```